# Passing many variables vs. passing struct

Tags: c, performance, pointers, struct

When passing several pointers to a function, in terms of performance only:
is is better to pass a pointer to a struct with all the pointers inside and then do something like code 1 or passing the pointers to variables directly?

I think that for small number of variables, the option two outperforms option 1 for sure, but is that the case when we have, say, 100 variables?

I found some questions about this, but none very conclusive in terms of performance only.

[What is better practise in high-performance computing: passing a struct of data into a function or a set of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041181/what-is-better-practise-in-high-performance-computing-passing-a-struct-of-data)

[Efficiency of passing a struct to a function without instantiating a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207395/efficiency-of-passing-a-struct-to-a-function-without-instantiating-a-local-varia)

[Declaring/passing structs vs. declaring/passing individual values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297897/declaring-passing-structs-vs-declaring-passing-individual-values/13590535#13590535)

OPTION 1

```
void myFunctionOne(void *pointerToStruct){
    struct myTypeOfStruct *localPointerToStruct;
    localPointerToStruct = (struct myTypeOfStruct *)pointerToStruct;

    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        *(localPointerToStruct->a+i) = sth;
        *(localPointerToStruct->b+i) = sthElse;
        ...
        *(localPointerToStruct->z+i) = sthElsez;
    }
}
```

OPTION 2

```
void myFunctionOne(double *a, double *b,...,double *z){
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        *(a+i) = sth;
        *(b+i) = sthElse;
        ...
        *(z+i) = sthElsex;
    }
}
```

OPTION 3

A third option that might seem a bit weird would be doing the first case but instead of iterating over the pointers inside the struct, copy them to local pointer variables.

```
void myFunctionOne(void *pointerToStruct){
    struct myTypeOfStruct *localPointerToStruct;
    localPointerToStruct = (struct myTypeOfStruct *)pointerToStruct;

        double *a = localPointerToStruct->a;
        double *b = localPointerToStruct->b;
        ...
        double *z = localPointerToStruct->z;

    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        *(a+i) = sth;
        *(b+i) = sthElse;
        ...
        *(z+i) = sthElsex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by asking why you would define the function to take a `void*` only to cast it so a non-`void*`. You'd only do that if there was some external constraint on the function prototype (like in `pthread_create()`), in which case you would not even have the option of passing multiple `double*` instead.

Comment: @EOF Thank you, that's right and I guess I inherited that from the previous version of the code.

Comment: Btw, I just realized that if I have a pointer to a struct and in that struct there are pointers I think I should have written: `*(localPointerToStruct->a+i) = sth;` instead of:  `*(localPointerToStruct.a+i) = sth;` Am I right? (someone confirm so I edit the question)

Comment: Yes, using `.` operator on a `struct foo*` will not compile. You *could* do `(*pointer).member`, but `pointer->member` is easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to evaluate the overall efficiency of the approach you need to consider the way the function call is made, because the efficiency of the first approach depends a great deal on where does the `struct` come from.

If you have to perform the same `struct` set-up before each call, the first approach becomes identical to the second approach, except now you are in charge of preparing the stack frame for the function.

If, on the other hand, you can set up your `struct` once, and then make multiple calls with it, you will end up with less copying.

For the sake of completeness, if you have to allocate your struct dynamically, the performance is going to be significantly worse.

One important advantage of the `struct` approach is maintenance. If you decide to add another field to a `struct`, you just add another field to the `struct`, and everything continues to compile. However, adding an extra parameter to a function would force you to revisit all places in code where you make the call, and add a new argument expression for the newly added parameter.

I would modify the first approach to take `myTypeOfStruct` instead of `void*`, because there is no point to hide parameter type. After all, the alternative passes arrays of `double` directly, without `void*` cast. I would also prefer array syntax to pointer manipulation:

```
void myFunctionOne(struct myTypeOfStruct *pointerToStruct){
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        pointerToStruct->a[i] = sth;
        pointerToStruct->b[i] = sthElse;
        ...
        pointerToStruct->z[i] = sthElsez;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. If the struct remains the same within several calls, then approach 1 seems better. But, may I ask you, what do you think is the effect of accessing struct elements vs. elements not in a struct?

Because I would say that basically accessing `struct.a` is probably as fast/slow as accessing element from an array `array[4]` which is clear that is slower than accessing to variable `x` itself, right?
So, wouldn't also having many accesses to `struct.a` lead to slower code compared with having just accesses to `x`?

Comment: @myradio In the world without optimizing compilers the answer would be "yes". Fortunately, optimizing compilers are smart: they would read the pointer to struct only once, and keep it in a register for instantaneous dereference, i.e. the same thing that they would do with an individual pointer passed as a function parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the compiler which does a lot of background optimization and environment. Generally don't try to outsmart the compiler, but if you really, really need it make a test with some million calls to each of the options, in 3 different programs of course and after rebooting your pc after each test. Then you know for what it's worth what was more performant on that exact moment in time with your exact setup.

Answer (score 2):

In general, use a `struct` to aggregate variables that belong together and pass a pointer to that `struct` to your functions. That will be the fastest way. But of course in that case, the function *can* modify the `struct` and those modifications will be reflected in the caller. You can obviate this using `const`.

But in general, trust the compiler to make the optimisations for you, and only worry about micro-optimising if that area of code has been identified as a bottleneck.

Comment: Ha. Silly old cat. I was misreading the position of `*`.Should have gone to Specsavers. Edited to (i) salvage some dignity and (ii) allow folk to retract upvotes.

Comment: @Bathsheba Even regarding to fact that `localPointerToStruct` is a pointer and we have deal with pointer assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Performance (of arguments & results passing) depends upon the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) used by your C implementation.
BTW, an optimizing C compiler will often [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) a function call (even for functions not declared `inline`, as long as it knows the definition of the called function). And some compilers are able of link-time optimizations (with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile *and link* with `gcc -flto -O2`)

Notice that on Linux/x86-64 the ABI [specification](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) dictates that the first 6 scalar arguments are generally passed by registers, and that a result which is a `struct` of two scalars is passed thru two registers. This is generally much faster than passing thru memory (e.g. on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)).

At last, the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) matters a lot for performance. So the only way to really know is to benchmark your application.